# Angular 2 RC1 - Setting default option on select

Tags: angular

all ! I've this...

```
    <select #sel [(ngModel)]="sort">
        <option *ngFor="let xOptions of sortOptions">{{xOptions}}   </option>
    </select>
```

with this code:

```
sortOptions = ["Op1", "Op2"];
```

How to set the default to Op2 ?

It's not working: this.sort = "Op2";
I saw some docs that's says to set the model. Maybe something changed in RC1 ? ty !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 2.0.0-beta.14 an object can be bound to  using ngValue (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#user-content-200-beta14-2016-04-07), so try to add `[ngValue]="xOptions"` like this:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="sort">
  <option *ngFor="let xOptions of sortOptions" [ngValue]="xOptions">{{xOptions}}</option>
</select>
```

See also plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/vLSiuQKQNbwFkIQ70j81?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Since `sortOptions` is an array of primitive values, you can bind to the `value` property of each `option` element:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="sort">
  <option [value]="sortOption" *ngFor="let sortOption of sortOptions">{{xOptions}}</option>
</select>
```

```ts
export class MyComponent {
  sortOptions = ["Op1", "Op2"];
  sort = "Opt2";   // or,  sort = this.sortOptions[1];
  ...
}
```

---

If `sortOptions` contained an array of objects, then use `ngValue` to bind each object to each `option` element, as @yurzui shows in his answer.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `ng-model` if you binding data into drop down list from @model. Or can use `ng-selected`